# Problem with equation in complex numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

> I am supposed to calculate:
>
> $x^{2}=5+i$

I used formula:

$\left | \cos \frac{\alpha }{2} \right |=\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos \alpha }{2}}$

$\left | \sin \frac{\alpha }{2} \right |=\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos  \alpha }{2}}$

and I came to the point where:

x= $\sqrt[4]{26}\left ( \frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{26}+5}}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt[4]{26}}  + i \frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{26}-5}}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt[4]{26}} \right)$= $\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{26}+5}}{\sqrt{2}}  + i \frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{26}-5}}{\sqrt{2}} $

I know that k=0,1 and also that  $\sin x, \cos x $ are positive in the first quadrant, so my solution will simple be :

$x_{0}=\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{26}+5}}{\sqrt{2}}  + i \frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{26}-5}}{\sqrt{2}} $

$x_{1}=-\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{26}+5}}{\sqrt{2}}  + i \frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{26}-5}}{\sqrt{2}} $

It does not seem like the correct solution. Can anyone please tell me, where I made the mistake?

Comment: I am not sure where the mistake is. However, since the equation is quadratic, trigonometry could be avoided by setting $x=a+bi$, expand and set real and imaginary parts equal. It may not come out nice (square roots you can't take) moreover there are only 2 solutions (why?)

Comment: @imranfat yes, I made the mistake, there are just two, because x is to the power of two .. but I did, what you wrote and that is solution.. unless I made a mistake

Comment: It does not come out nice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also write $$5+i=a^2-b^2+2abi$$ so we will get $$5=a^2-b^2$$ and $$1=2ab$$
Plugging $$b=\frac{1}{2a}$$ in the first equation you will get
$$20a^2=4a^4-1$$

Comment: Will it be helpful in my problem?

Comment: I think yes, solve the system of equations and you will get the solution.

Comment: Eliminating $b$ you will get for $a$: $$0=a^4-5a^2-\frac{1}{4}$$

Comment: It might be helpful to add to the answer that $a^2 - b^2 + 2abi = (a + bi)^2 = x^2$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I do not understand.. I understand your elimination, but I do not know how to solve it for a or what to do next

Comment: Probably you know how to solve for $c$ in the equation $$0 = c^2 - 5c - \frac{1}{4}$$ and that will probably help you to quickly solve for $a$ in the equation $$0 = a^4 - 5a^2 - \frac{1}{4}$$

Comment: @LeeMosher yes, okay thank you

Answer (score 0):

$5 + i = \rho (\cos \theta + i\sin theta)\\
\sqrt{\rho (\cos \theta + i\sin \theta)} = \sqrt {\rho}(\cos \frac \theta2 + i\sin \frac \theta2)\\
\rho = \sqrt {5^2 + 1} = \sqrt {26}\\
\theta = \arctan \frac {1}{5}\\
\cos \theta = \frac {5}{\sqrt {26}}\\
\sin\theta = \frac {1}{\sqrt {26}}\\
\tan \frac{\theta}{2} = \frac {1-\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}= \frac {1 - \frac {5}{\sqrt{26}}}{\frac {1}{\sqrt {26}}} = \sqrt {26} - 5\\
$